# Efficent way to to get values from one pandas dataframe based on a conditon into another pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two data sets. One contains 3 ish million proposed work shifts.
you can think of the data as resembling this

| Day | Start | End | Worker ID | Store ID | Shift ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/17/2020 | 16:00. | 22:00 | 123456. | 123 | 12345 |
| 12/13/2020 | 17:00. | 23:00 | 2889785. | 321 | 34346 |

**One worker can do multiple shifts on the same day **

the second data set is a set of 4 million ish punches. These punches are records of a worker punching in/out for lunch/ back from lunch/out for the actual shift they did.

the data looks like this

| Worker Id | Store ID | Punch Code | Punch time | Punch Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 123 | IN. | 16:00. | 12/17/2020 |
| 2889785 | 321 | OUT. | 23:00. | 12/13/2020 |
| 123456 | 123. | LUNCH OUT. | 17:10. | 12/17/2020 |

I need to make a dataframe that preferably looks like this

| Worker Id | Store ID | Punch Code | Punch time | Punch Date | Shift ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 123 | IN. | 16:00. | 12/17/2020 | 12345. |
| 2889785 | 321 | OUT. | 23:00. | 12/13/2020 | 34346 |
| 123456 | 123. | LUNCH OUT. | 17:10. | 12/17/2020 | 12345. |

I would prefer to do a merge where the On is on store,worker,id and then an |||if the punch time is within the given shift range |||

but as far as im aware you cannot do a conditional merge ?

I cant seem to think of a way to do this in pandas

I have tried looping over the frames list of dicts but this is going to take a long long time as it requires so much nested looping.

I have also considered constructing an apply function that takes in store,time,and id and finds the shift in question returning the id to the column. This i think is the neatest most satisfying way to do it but would i believe also take far too long.

It feels like there must be a 'vectorized' way of achieving this but maybe not -- any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at conditional_join from pyjanitor. It should work for your use case

Answer (score 0):

You can try to minimize searches by first creating *index* - in this case dictionary of groups where keys are `Day`/`Store ID`/`Worker ID`:

```py
# create datetime objects from df1
df1["Shift_Start"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Day"] + " " + df1["Start"])
df1["Shift_End"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Day"] + " " + df1["End"])

# cretate punch datetime object
df2["Punch_Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Punch Date"] + " " + df2["Punch time"])

# create groups for easy searching
groups_day_store_worker_id = {
    idx: g for idx, g in df1.groupby(["Day", "Store ID", "Worker ID"])
}


def get_shift_id(row):
    group = groups_day_store_worker_id.get(
        (row["Punch Date"], row["Store ID"], row["Worker Id"])
    )
    if group is None:
        return None

    punch_time = row["Punch_Time"]
    for s, e, shift_id in zip(
        group["Shift_Start"], group["Shift_End"], group["Shift ID"]
    ):
        if s <= punch_time <= e:
            return shift_id

    return None


df2["Shift ID"] = df2.apply(get_shift_id, axis=1)
print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
   Worker Id  Store ID Punch Code Punch time  Punch Date          Punch_Time  Shift ID
0     123456       123         IN      16:00  12/17/2020 2020-12-17 16:00:00     12345
1    2889785       321        OUT      23:00  12/13/2020 2020-12-13 23:00:00     34346
2     123456       123  LUNCH OUT      17:10  12/17/2020 2020-12-17 17:10:00     12345
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to merge your shift data with the punch data, then create a mask for rows where the punch time is between the start and end times to select the rows you want. First I had to clean up your sample data (you may not need to do this):

```py
shifts['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(shifts['Day'])
shifts['Start'] = shifts['Start'].str.strip('. ')
shifts['Worker ID'] = shifts['Worker ID'].astype(int)

punchs['Store ID'] = punchs['Store ID'].astype(int)
punchs['Punch time'] = punchs['Punch time'].str.strip(' .')
punchs['Punch Date'] = pd.to_datetime(punchs['Punch Date'])
```

Then we can process it:

```py
out = punchs.merge(shifts, 
     left_on=['Worker Id', 'Store ID', 'Punch Date'],
     right_on=['Worker ID', 'Store ID', 'Day'], 
     how='inner')
mask = (out['Start'] <= out['Punch time']) & (out['Punch time'] <= out['End'])
out = out[mask].drop(columns=['Day', 'Start', 'End', 'Worker ID'])
```

Output for your sample data:

```
   Worker Id  Store ID   Punch Code Punch time Punch Date  Shift ID
0     123456       123         IN.       16:00 2020-12-17     12345
1     123456       123  LUNCH OUT.       17:10 2020-12-17     12345
2    2889785       321        OUT.       23:00 2020-12-13     34346
```